# Where is my application installed?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting errors like `com.ibm.icu` etc are missing from `/home/jiewmeng/eclipse/plugins/*`. I think it might be because I am working on the project from 2 different computers where the eclipse paths maybe different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To find package installation defaults:

```
dpkg -L <package_name>
```

--Snippet Example:

```
dpkg -L firefox
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/firefox-addons
/usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions
/usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
/usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}/install.rdf
/usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}/icon.png
/usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}/preview.png
/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins
/usr/lib/firefox-addons/searchplugins
```

Comment: Oh I get an error about ecplise not installed, I think I installed it from the tar file ... hmm. Arr I found it.

Comment: works for more that ecplise